# JavaScript average while loop

Tags: javascript

The question - 
Develop a class averaging script that will process an arbitrary number of results each time it is run. Prompt the user for each of the results until he/she types in -1.  (A sentinel) 
Determine the Class Average and write it to the page.
If no results are entered (first input is -1) display a message indicating that.

My output is way off and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script>

var result;
var index = 0;
var average = 0 ;
var sum = 0;

result = prompt("Please enter your grade, enter -1 to exit");
parseInt(result);

if(result == -1)
{
    alert("no input");
}
else
{

    while(result != -1)
    {
        sum = result + sum;         //adds on result to current sum
        index++;
        average = sum / index;      //index divided by sum to get average

        result = prompt("Please enter a number, enter -1 to exit");
        parseInt(result);


    }
    document.write("average = " + average);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```js
var result;
var index = 0;
var average = 0 ;
var sum = 0;

result = prompt("Please enter your grade, enter -1 to exit");
result =parseInt(result);//changed

if(result == -1)
{
alert("no input");
}
else
{

while(result != -1)
{
sum = result + sum;         //adds on result to current sum
index++;
average = sum / index;      //index divided by sum to get average

result = prompt("Please enter a number, enter -1 to exit");
result =parseInt(result);//changed


}
document.write("average = " + average);

}
```

You were missing assignment of `result`

Answer (score 3):

You have to re-assign result, not just cast it to int

`result = parseInt(result)`

Or you can quick-cast the operation as (dirty way):

`sum = +result + +sum;`

`+` before variables mean 'process the variable as integer'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reassign the parsed result when data is inserted.

```
result = parseInt(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere set `parseInt();` if you are using only integers or `parseFloat();` for decimal numbers, because you need to convert them before making any operations.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() for every round integer value and assign back to result variable.

```
result = parseInt(result);
```